# ROS Gazebo URDF Joint Control works with position controller but not any other type

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've noticed a few other questions of a similar nature usually having trouble with namespaces when trying to control joints in ROS Gazebo. I think I've got the namespaces down, but I'm having a weird issue where everything works fine when I use a position controller, but as soon as I try to switch to any other type of controller I get errors. Here are the relevant parts of the files of the working version with position controllers.

Relevant section of urdf:

```
<transmission name="antenna_rotation">
 <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
 <actuator name="$antenna_motor">
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
</actuator>
 <joint name="antenna_base_to_antenna">
  <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
 </joint>
</transmission>

 <!-- plugin needed to control robot using ros -->
 <gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/antenna_robot</robotNamespace>
  </plugin>
 </gazebo>
```

Relevant section of launch file, I have the whole robot under its own namespace since I am using 2 different robots.

```
<group ns="antenna_robot">
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen" args="-file $(find 
     antenna_sim_description)/com_base_station/model.urdf -urdf -x 6.5 -y -6.5 -z 0 -model antenna" />

<arg name="model" default="$(find antenna_sim_description)/com_base_station/model.urdf"/>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />

  <rosparam command="load"
      file="$(find antenna_sim_description)/com_base_station/config/joints.yaml"
      ns="antenna_sim_joint_state_controller" />

    <rosparam command="load"
      file="$(find antenna_sim_description)/com_base_station/config/antenna.yaml"
      ns="antenna_sim_antenna_controller" />
            
    <node name="antenna_sim_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner"
      args="antenna_sim_joint_state_controller
      antenna_sim_antenna_controller" />
  </group>
```

joints.yaml:

```
type: "joint_state_controller/JointStateController"
publish_rate: 50
```

antenna.yaml:

```
type: "position_controllers/JointPositionController"
joint: antenna_base_to_antenna
```

Everything works great, can this command to rotate the antenna for example:

```
rostopic pub /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_antenna_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: -0.707"
```

Now I try to switch to a different type of controller, I change my urdf to VelocityJointInterface
I change my antenna.yaml to velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController

I get the following errors when I launch:

```
[ERROR] [1553738576.470885508, 1298.720000000]: Could not find 'joints' parameter (namespace: /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_antenna_controller).
[ERROR] [1553738576.470958595, 1298.720000000]: Failed to initialize the controller
[ERROR] [1553738576.471007007, 1298.720000000]: Initializing controller 'antenna_sim_antenna_controller' failed
[ INFO] [1553738577.027059438, 1299.280000000]: Datum (latitude, longitude, altitude) is (49.900000, 8.900000, 0.000000)
[ INFO] [1553738577.027100296, 1299.280000000]: Datum UTM coordinate is (492818.438771, 5527517.135857)
[ INFO] [1553738577.027129711, 1299.280000000]: Initial odometry pose is Origin: (0 0 0)
Rotation (RPY): (0, -0, 0)
[ INFO] [1553738577.027219487, 1299.280000000]: Corrected for magnetic declination of 0.000000, user-specified offset of 1.570796 and meridian convergence of -0.001335. Transform heading factor is now 1.569461
[ INFO] [1553738577.027244788, 1299.280000000]: Transform world frame pose is: Origin: (0 0 0)
Rotation (RPY): (0, -0, 0)

[ INFO] [1553738577.027269780, 1299.280000000]: World frame->utm transform is Origin: (-5528170.1551857395098 485438.39578638831154 0)
Rotation (RPY): (0, 0, -1.5694612597485673167)

[ERROR] [1553738577.472082, 1299.720000]: Failed to load antenna_sim_antenna_controller
```

Not sure how this is happening. I've double checked to make sure I have all the controller types installed and I can see that the yaml file is being parsed based on these parameters showing up in the terminal after launching (before the error messages):

```
PARAMETERS
 * /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_antenna_controller/joint: antenna_base_to_a...
 * /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_antenna_controller/type: velocity_controll...
 * /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319769/ros-gazebo-urdf-joint-control-works-with-position-controller-but-not-any-other-type/) by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is in your configuration.

First you use:

```
type: "position_controllers/JointPositionController"
joint: antenna_base_to_antenna
```

Which is a `JointPositionController` in the `position_controllers` package.

Then you state (emphasis mine):

> Now I try to switch to a different type of controller, I change my urdf to VelocityJointInterface I change my antenna.yaml to **velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController**

That is a different controller (provided by the `joint_trajectory_controller` package) and it requires different parameters, one of which is the `joints` parameter ([here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/1c98237023648d8ab8d4ca6b7f3238ad6b9af942/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller_impl.h#L244)).

You only have `joint` in your `antenna.yaml`, so you'll have to change it.

This is also clear from the error message in the console output you show:

```
[ERROR] [1553738576.470885508, 1298.720000000]: Could not find 'joints' parameter (namespace: /antenna_robot/antenna_sim_antenna_controller).
```

Please also note that `joint_trajectory_controller`s will require you to send [FollowJointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) goals. A single `std_msgs/Float64` will no longer work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0